# Laptop Sleep automatically when android studio run

Tags: android, windows, android-studio

I have a strange issue with my laptop. This issue is that when i run app or while build.gradle run it goes to sleep. The issue only occurs while android studio run.
The issue is with the new version of android studio 3.0.1. previously it was working fine.

Comment: What about your System ?? tell me your system Configurations detail

Comment: Its has 8gb (DDR 4) of ram , 500gb hdd , windows 10 , 2.7GHz of i7 intel.

Comment: all good, this is problem is hardware problem not an Software problem

Answer (score 0):

That is strange. I don't seem to think it's an issue with Android Studio. Check the power settings in your laptop by going to power and sleep settings and check for the timeout that you have kept. Try disabling sleep. Also did you check if this happens when your battery is low? Change power mode to better performance or best performance if you are using Windows 10. Reply if it still doesn't seem to fix the issue.

Comment: I have checked all of my windows sleep setting like sleep after 5 hour on battery, no sleep while charging. Most of time i use android studio while charging.

Comment: Run power troubleshooter.
On the search bar type “Troubleshooting” and Click on “View All” left panel.Click Power, new window will popup.

Answer (score 0):

So issue resolved after i restart my laptop. Now its working fine. I think the issue was with the constant running of the laptop for long interval of time, because the laptop was powered on for 2 days.